# Can't remember name of board game

Tags: identify-this-game

So in the very early 2000s (in the U.K.), I had this board game that was essentially a large purple monster head. I was quite young at the time so I can't fully remember the rules of the game either, but it was something like a player has to place or retrieve plastic bugs from the monsters mouth without it noticing and spitting at you. I've asked family members about this game and nobody seems to remember it except my Dad but like me he can't remember what it was called at all. Help!

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like [Purple People Eater](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/244254/purple-people-eater) by Waddington's.

Comment: I found what appears to be an image of this game:

http://www.theoldtoyguide.com/2015/02/19/70-s-game-waddingtons-purple-people-eater-rare-electrical-game-working-complete/

Answer (score 0):

Could it be this game : [hongerige harrie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jiwrBuTkVh8) ?

Seems strange though, because it is listed on BGG ([link](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/177879/hongerige-harrie)) as a 2013 game.

[Edit : The Youtube video says that it is "[slime monster game](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/10967/slime-monster-game)" from 1977, but it appears that "slime monster game" is another game.]